# HTML remove space between integer and fraction when using &frasl;

Tags: html

How can I remove the space in a mixed number between the whole number (e.g. 2) and the fraction (e.g. 7⁄16) when using `&frasl;`?

`2 7&frasl;16` displays 2 7⁄16 (w/ a space between 2 and the fraction)

`27&frasl;16` displays 27⁄16

So it display as... `2&frac16;` as this would for 2⅙

Is there a code, essentially the 'reverse' of `&nbsp;` for an 'empty space'?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a zero-width non-joiner character (`&zwnj;`)(https://htmlhelp.org/reference/html40/entities/special.html)

```html
2&zwnj;7&frasl;16
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:
`2&#173;7&frasl;16` produces 2­7⁄16

I can live with that, though if there are better ways to do this, please advise.

Comment: Semantically that wouldn't be correct, and it may not also work with screen readers. `&#173` is a soft hyphen

Comment: @j08691 agreed... I just haven't figured out another way to pull it off. I welcome suggestions.

Comment: You see the answer I posted, yes?